# Expressing $\cos(\varphi x)$ as a function of $x\sin\varphi,x\cos\varphi$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus, trigonometry

Let $\varphi,x\in\mathbb{R}$. I wonder if one can explicitly express $\cos(\varphi x)$ as a function of the variables $x\sin\varphi$ and $x\cos\varphi$.

Suppose we denote $t_1=x\cos\varphi,t_2=x\sin\varphi$, $$x=\sqrt{t_1^2+t_2^2} \\ \cos\varphi= \frac{t_1}{\sqrt{t_1^2+t_2^2}} \\ \sin\varphi =\frac{t_2}{\sqrt{t_1^2+t_2^2}}$$

Can we get a "convenient" expression for $\cos(\varphi x)$ using the variables above?

Comment: what variable is $x$? found it

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner A real variable ($\varphi$ too).

Comment: If $x$ is an integer there are the addition theorems which lead to expressions involving the Chebyshev polynomials.

Comment: @Zardo, I also thought about it but alas I'm looking for a solution for **real values** of x.

Comment: Are you searching for this http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Multiple-AngleFormulas.html ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think so. Even if you get $\cos \varphi$ and $\sin \varphi$, if you are not given the range of $\varphi$, there are still many possible values of $\varphi$, hence many possible values of $\cos \varphi x$, because
$$\cos(\varphi + 2\pi) x = \cos(\varphi x + 2\pi x) \ne \cos \varphi x$$
for non-integer $x$.

Comment: but if we restrict the problem to $\varphi\in[0,\pi]$, can we get a closed form for the expression?

Comment: @Nir Then you can get $\varphi$ from $\cos \varphi$ using $\arccos$.

Comment: @Nir But be careful that $x$ has the same sign as $x\sin\varphi$ for your range $\varphi \in [0,\pi]$. If $x\sin\varphi < 0$ then you have to adjust the formulae for $x$, $\cos \varphi$ and $\sin\varphi$.